# mediastreamvalidator throws "Error Injecting Segment data"

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, hls

`mediastreamvalidator` throws "Error Injecting Segment data" for fMP4+hevc+HLS file. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4uMQ.png) is the attached screenshot. How to fix it to make it playable ?